# Multi threading Process for Audio Applications

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, audio

I’m currently trying to design an audio sampler that takes many audio files, adds filters, mixes them together and then outputs the result to the speakers. I’m hoping to multithread this process to make it go faster, but I’m not sure which of two routes I should take:

1. One function that runs on multiple threads that does everything (input file, add filter, output)
2. Multiple threads that do different tasks ie. Thread 1 gets input samples and adds them to an array to be processed, Thread 2 gets the items in the first array, filters each one and then adds them to a second array Thread 3 takes the processed samples in the second array and outputs them to the speakers

Which of these approaches would be best, or is there a better approach that I’m missing? I’m hoping to do Float32 output at 192khz.